# FileNotFoundError Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, file-not-found

I'm getting a `FileNotFoundError` in `Jupyter Notebook` although I think my directory is correct and I have the correct file in said directory. Sorry if I display the code/error incorrectly this is my first time posting a question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import os
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Wildcat\Desktop\New folder(2)\temperatues.csv')




---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8fd0e35f001e> in <module>()
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Wildcat\Desktop\New folder(2)\temperatues.csv')

~\Desktop\New folder (2)\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Desktop\New folder (2)\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    403 
    404     # Create the parser.
--> 405     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    406 
    407     if chunksize or iterator:

~\Desktop\New folder (2)\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    762             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    763 
--> 764         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    765 
    766     def close(self):

~\Desktop\New folder (2)\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    983     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    984         if engine == 'c':
--> 985             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    986         else:
    987             if engine == 'python':

~\Desktop\New folder (2)\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1603         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1604 
-> 1605         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1606 
   1607         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:4209)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:8873)()

FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\\Users\\Wildcat\\Desktop\\New folder(2)\\temperatues.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: I think it is the funny newfolder(2). rename it as something sensible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will make sure to try it out and get back to you.